# Possible memory issue with a simple C linked list program

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to write a program which will count the occurrence of words in a paragraph.

The logic I am following : I am using a linked list for the purpose. And I am searching sequentially - if new word encountered adding the word in the list, but if word already exist in the list increase its count flag.

```
//case insensitive string matching
int strcicmp(char const *a, char const *b)
{
    int d;
    for(;;a++,b++)
    {
        d=tolower(*a)-tolower(*b);
        if(d!=0 || !*a)
            return d;
    }
}

//declare the linked list structure to store distinct words and their count
typedef struct node
{
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *ptr, *newnode, *first=NULL, *last=NULL;

void insertnewword(char *ch)
{
    newnode=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(newnode == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nMemory is not allocated\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        newnode->word=ch;
        newnode->count=1;
        newnode->next=NULL;
    }           

    if(first==last && last==NULL)
    {
        first=last=newnode;
        first->next=NULL;
        last->next=NULL;
    }   
    else
    {
        last->next=newnode;     
        last=newnode;
        last->next=NULL;            
    }   
}

void processword(char *ch)
{   
    int found=0;
    //if word is already in the list, increase the count
    for(ptr=first;ptr!=NULL;ptr=ptr->next)          
        if(strcicmp(ptr->word, ch) == 0)
        {
            ptr->count += 1;
            found=1;
            break;
        }

    //if it's a new word, add the word to the list
    if(!found)
        insertnewword(ch);  
}

int main()
{
    const char *delimiters=" ~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]:;<,>.?/|\\\'\"\t\n\r";
    char *ch, *str; 
    str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    ch=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

    //get the original string
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str);
    //fgets(str, 500, stdin);

    //get the tokenized string
    ch=strtok(str,delimiters);
    while(ch!=NULL)
    {
        //a, an, the should not be counted
        if(strcicmp("a", ch)!=0 && strcicmp("an", ch)!=0 && strcicmp("the", ch)!=0)
            processword(ch);        

        ch=strtok(NULL,delimiters);
    }

    //print the word and it's occurrence count
    for(ptr=first; ptr!=NULL; ptr=ptr->next)
        printf("%s\t\t%d\n",ptr->word,ptr->count);
    return 0;
}
```

this seem to be working fine for few number of words, but if word count is more than 6-7, this program is encountering some problem.

Say input is : I am a good boy. I am a bad Boy.

Input should be

I 2
am 2
good 1
bad 1
boy 2

But what I am getting is
I 2
am 2
good 1
bad 1
(some garbage character) 1

I can always implement any other logic for the same problem, but I want to know the issue with this implementation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char))`? Certainly not. You probably want to allocate a longer buffer for your string. (`sizeof(char)` is always 1 and can be omitted.)

Comment: `strtok` returns a pointer into already existing memory; you don't have to allocate memory to it. (Or rather. You mus not allocate memory to it: This will inroduce a memory leak, because you overwrite `ch` and lose the only reference to the allocated memory.)

Comment: Thank you M Oehm for helping me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem come from your scanf:

`in the man scanf:
the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the characters in the  string,  plus  a terminating  null  byte`

but in the top of your main, the allocation of your char array is juste one bite long:
`str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));`

I think it would be better to use function like getline

`ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`
and setting lineptr pointing to NULL

Answer (score 0):

I think your linked list implementation is not causing you the problems but your memory allocation is causing you the actual problems.

First memory allocation problem:

```
str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
ch=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Here str and ch should have memory to hold the complete word along with terminating null character but you have allocated only one byte(i.e. size of char)

Second memory allocation problem:

```
newnode->word=ch;
```

This code fragment is present in your insertnewword() function.
Here you have allocated memory to your new node but you have not allocated any memory to the char *word present inside new node. After that you are directly making newnode->word point to ch which is a local variable of main() function.
When you complete the first word and tokenize the input string further, ch contains next word from the string. Now this may corrupt data in your linked list as you have made newnode->word directly point to ch.

So please allocate memory to word field present in newnode and copy the contents of ch into it.

I hope this will solve your problem.